# Python - sklearn PLSRegression: why is T != X0*W (scores, scaled data, weights, respectively)

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, partial-least-squares

Pretty much a complete newbie with PLS, Python, stats, (and stackexchange), sorry:

When using sklearn for PLSRegression, why is the resulting scores matrix **not** given by the product of (scaled) input and the weights matrix?

I.e. T = X0 * W

Minimum working example showing this is given below.

I have figured out in the meantime that the scores can be calculated according to an algorithm shown, e.g., here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003267086800289?via%3Dihub and that the scores can be calculated via the '.transform' method. But I struggle to understand why this choice was made. Can anyone tell me what's the benefit of having it this way?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

```
import numpy as np

# PLS tools 
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression

# just some numbers
X = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([3,4,5]),np.diag([5,4,1]),100)
y = np.dot(X,np.array([1,2,3]))+np.random.random(size=(100,))

pls = PLSRegression(n_components=2)
pls.fit(scale(X),y)

(pls.x_scores_ - np.dot(scale(X),pls.x_weights_)) / pls.x_scores_  # differ significantly from second column on forward
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please specify what you are observing and what you are expecting?

Comment: Sorry for not making my question clearer.


I was expecting the scores matrix to be given by the product of the scaled and centered inputs and the weight matrix. In fact, I thought this was an inherent feature of PLS.


Apparently, I was wrong and this is not the case for NIPALS. I was wondering whether there was any particular reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to NIPALS algorithm. In that algorithm, as the paper you referred shows, you deflate $X$ block while building up $Y$ block.

So you don't have a single $W$ matrix that can be applied to $X$ directly, instead the steps for calculation of scores are as following:

start with

$E = X$

for the first component (or latent variable, LV)

$t_1 = E w_1$

$E = E - (t_1p_1')$

for the second component

$t_2 = Ew_2$

$E = E - (t_2p_2')$

and so on...

Where $t_h$ is the $h^{th}$ scores vector, $w_h$ is the $h^{th}$ weights vector and  $p_h$ is the $h^{th}$ loading vector of $X$

There is, however, another algorithm called [SIMPLS](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016974399385002X) which provides you exactly what you need; a single weights matrix to be applied directly on the $X$. In that manner, I personally find NIPALS to be confusing and SIMPLS to be superior.

**TL;DR** The reason is the NIPALS algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Are you aware of a good python package for PLS that uses SIMPLS? I suspect this would make comparison with software that my colleagues use a bit easier.

Comment: I couldn't find any and I am not a python user. However, the algorithm is fairly easy to implement. The SIMPLS is the main algorithm for PLS in MATLAB and is available in R also.